Mixins in typescript with private fields
Is it possible to use private fields in mixins? I want to keep a single field internally, but the TS compiler says that mixins can only have protected or private fields.
ChatGPT suggests a map, which means a lookup every time I want to use the field.
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

class BaseClass {
    name = "BaseClass";
}

function ExampleMixin<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase) {
    return class extends Base {
        private secret: string = "This is private"; // Private field causing the export issue

        getSecret() {
            return this.secret;
        }
    };
}

// Attempt to export the mixin function
export const MixedClass = ExampleMixin(BaseClass);


please provide MRE in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Added an example

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30355

If you do not want to expose anything from the mixin, simply specify an explicit return value (that the mixed class is the only public API):
type Constructor<T = {}> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

class BaseClass {
    name = "BaseClass";
}

//returns TBase
function ExampleMixin<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase): TBase {
    return class extends Base {
        private secret: string = "This is private";

        getSecret() {
            return this.secret;
        }
    };
}

export const MixedClass = ExampleMixin(BaseClass);

If you want to expose partial API from the mixin, define an interface and tell that the return value is a combination of the class and the interface:
export interface PartialInterface
{
    publicProp: string;
}

function ExampleMixin<TBase extends Constructor>(Base: TBase): Constructor<PartialInterface> & TBase {
    return class extends Base {
        private secret: string = "This is private"; 
        publicProp = "hello";
        getSecret() {
            return this.secret;
        }
    };
}

export const MixedClass = ExampleMixin(BaseClass);

